# No route matches [DELETE] "/api/v1/auth/sign_out"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I'm working on an Ionic app with a rails backend api. We're using devise_token_auth rails side and ng-token-auth for the Ionic side.

```
namespace :api do
   scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
   end
end
```

This creates piece of code creates MOST of the routes but it seems that the [DELETE] /auth/sign_out route is not created. But it does create a [GET] /auth/sign_out. Any ideas of why this is out how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check in your `config/initializers/devise.rb` initializer, there is probably a line:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

replace it with:

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```